# CSS and/or Bootstrap - How to split the screen vertically

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

How can I go about splitting the screen like in the screenshot? The website in the screenshot is mine and I've designed it in Elementor but now I want to code it. How can I do that with css and maybe Boostrap?

Visit mateusrdesign.com to check it for yourself.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhCPc.png)

[Screenshot #02 (notice how the screen is smaller and there is no horizontal scroll bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kI7la.png)

Here's what I've tried:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="left" class="col-3">
            <p>Place holder</p>
        </div>
        <div id="right" class="col-9">
            <p>Place holder</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've also been trying, unsuccessfully, to imitate that hero image on first page, locking it to the right side of the screen. Any hep with that too would also be much appreciated.

Comment: Your `.container` div is probably a child of another div (or the `<body>` itself) that has a `width` or `max-width`. Hence it doesn't "expand" to the edges of the screen. Please check the parent of your div or post the code with the parent div.

Answer (score 0):

```
<body style="height: 100vh;">
    <div class="row w-100 h-100">
        <div class="col bg-info">Left side</div>
        <div class="col bg-dark">Right side</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

This is one of the bootstrap way. Dont forget to import bootstrap cdn to html.

Comment: As i see there are other html items/tags.
If you want to set all page, under all elements, then you should use this as a wrapper/parent. The whole other content should be inside of this. 
Or you can set some css with absolute positioning etc. (Probably not the best practice.)

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand. What do you mean by using it as a wrapper? Putting the content inside the divs with classes bg-info and bg-dark (in your example) won't change the fact that they don't extend to the whole screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with a flex box:

```css
.row {
   display: flex; 
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   flex-direction: row;
}

.row #left {
    background: yellow; /** Just to emphasize vertical split visually. You can remove this */
    width: 50%;
}


.row #right {
    background: green; /** Just to emphasize vertical split visually. You can remove this */
    flex: 1;
}
```

Comment: You should share your entire HTML. You just need to make sure `height: 100%` or `height: 100vh` is applied to parent elements of the outer most `div` all the way through to the innermost `div`s i.e. with ids `left` and `right`

Comment: here's everything I have
https://github.com/mateusrdesign/mateusrdesign

Comment: @MateusRodrigues - sharing an offsite repository of code is not helpful for the purpose of SO-- that repo will not be searchable within SO, and once you update it the contents will no longer be useful for anyone coming to this post to try to solve a similar issue.  This is why the SO guidelines state a [mcve] should be included **in the body of the question.**